# AWS ECS dynamic port mapping + nginx + app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have a typical ECS infrastructure with a single app behind an ALB. I leverage dynamic host mapping for CD process (ECS can deploy a new container on the same host without port collision).

Now I want to add an nginx container in front of it (for SSL from ALB to EC2). The problem is, in nginx config, I have to specify the app endpoint with the port. With the port being assigned dynamically, I cannot hardcode this value into nginx config. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think trying to reach this dynamic port makes a lot of sense...

Currently your have only one nginx server running, so you have an application load balancer, that directs incoming traffic on port 80 to an EC2 instance, at the random port corresponding to your web server container.

```
<ALB domain name>:80 -> <container EC2 instance IP>:<container dynamic port>
```

But if your service was scaling up, you would have two containers, running on two different ports, possibly on different EC2 instances.

```
<ALB domain name>:80 -> <container EC2 instance IP>:<dynamic port>
                     -> <container2 EC2 instance IP>:<another dynamic port>
```

Your ALB would contact in round-robin each of these containers alternatively.

Mapping to one of these containers on its dynamic port directly would be losing the advantage of the load balancer by bypassing it.

So your proxy that adds SSL has to reach the load balancer itself, on its internal domain name (or the one you would have assigned in Route 53), on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You can use[JWilder Nginx Proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) docker container. This allows you to do the dynamic mapping using environmental variables which is configurable in ECS.

Comment: I guess my question is how do you query the dynamic port? In task def we just use 0 as host port.

Comment: When we had the issue with the dynamic port mappings, this jwilder nginx proxy implementation provided an alternative approach still to route the traffic to relevant containers. Here, instead relying on the dynamically mapped port, an Virtual Host environment variable is defined in each container with a DNS name. Then you can map DNS records to ALB(Which points to multiple Jwilder instances running in each EC2 host instance) and it knows how to forward them to the relevant containers. Is it fitting your purpose?

Comment: The instruction looks simple, but I didn't get it. Do I need to modify the source and rebuild it or I can just use the prebuilt version? Says I have an app exposed on 5000 on host (with VIRTUAL_HOST=app.domain.com), how does the nginx-proxy container knows which port to proxy?

Comment: You don't need to build it. All the mappings are handled using environmental variables.

Comment: So how does nginx-proxy know which port to proxy? My app is exposing on port 5000, how do I configure nginx to proxy port 80 to it?

Comment: When you specify the virtual host for your containers, internaly nginx proxy identifies the request through origin and forward it to the container which has the virtual host specified. Internally it will route to the container after identifying the container's port by virtual host environmental variable.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work... the VIRTUAL_HOST is the environment variable inside my app container, how can nginx-proxy see it/